# How to specify feed when using 'updateActivities' with Stream?

Tags: getstream-io

The `updateActivities` method in the Stream API is perplexing, as the docs seem to indicate that a feed is not specified during this operation. How is this supposed to work?

The other activity methods (`addActivity`, `removeActivity`) are performed on a feed object, which makes sense. But the docs show `updateActivities` as a method on the client object, with no way to specify the feed containing the activity.

From the docs:

```
var now = new Date();

activity = {
    "actor": "1",
    "verb":"like",
    "object": "3",
    "time": now.toISOString(),
    "foreign_id": "like:3",
    "popularity": 100
};

// first time the activity is added
user1.addActivity(activity);

// update the popularity value for the activity
activity.popularity = 10;

// send the update to the APIs
client.updateActivities([activity]);
```

My expectation (and the only thing that makes sense, as far as I can tell), would be that the `updateActivities` method would be on the feed object, since a `foreign_id` is not unique across all feeds.
(Previous assumption based on lots of experience using identical foreign IDs across multiple feeds.)

Answer (score 1):

When an activity is added to a feed, Stream generates a unique ID for it and uses such ID to propagate the activity to the direct feed and if any, to all follower feeds. In fact only references to activities are stored inside feeds.

Stream also guarantees that IDs are consistent for same `time` and `foreign_id` values. This means that if you add an activity with same time and foreign_id, it will always end up with the same ID.

This allows you to control activity uniqueness and to update all occurrences of an activity without keeping track of all feeds that can have a copy (the `to` target and follow relationships would make this a very complex task!).